# Wrong formatting in BlockSyntax of the method body

Tags: c#, roslyn

I wrote code which generate a class for WebAPI controller methods calling. When I try to generated method body I have problems with strings formatting like this:

```
    public async Task<String> HttpPost(Boolean isSuccess)
    {
            var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>(); var  request  =  RestSharpExtensions . PostRequest ( "Test" ,  "HttpPost" ,  isSuccess . ToString ( ) ) ;  var  handle  =  Client . ExecuteAsync ( request ,  r  =>  taskCompletion . SetResult ( r ) ) ;  var  response  =  await  taskCompletion . Task ;  return  JsonConvert . DeserializeObject < String > ( response . Content ) ; 
    }
```

This is the method which generated method body:

```
    private static BlockSyntax GetMethodBody(BaseApiMethodInfo methodInfo, string controllerName)
    {
        var body = new StringBuilder($"var taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();{Environment.NewLine}var request = ");
        var dataText = methodInfo.Data != null 
            ? methodInfo.Data.Item2.ToString() 
            : "null";

        var methodParameters = $"\"{controllerName}\", \"{methodInfo.Name}\", {dataText}.ToString()";
        string httpRequestText;
        switch (methodInfo.Method)
        {
            case Method.GET:
                httpRequestText = $"RestSharpExtensions.GetRequest({methodParameters});";
                break;
            case Method.POST:
                httpRequestText = $"RestSharpExtensions.PostRequest({methodParameters});";
                break;
            case Method.PUT:
                httpRequestText = $"RestSharpExtensions.PutRequest({methodParameters});";
                break;
            case Method.DELETE:
                httpRequestText = $"RestSharpExtensions.DeleteRequest({methodParameters});";
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("methodInfo.Method");                    
        }

        body.AppendLine(httpRequestText + Environment.NewLine);
        body.AppendLine($"var handle = Client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));{Environment.NewLine}");
        body.AppendLine($"var response = await taskCompletion.Task;{Environment.NewLine}");
        body.AppendLine($"return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<{TypesHelper.GetTypeName(methodInfo.ReturnedType)}>(response.Content);");

        return Block(ParseStatement(body.ToString()));
    }
```

Unfortunately i did't find any points to solve this problem. This is the referense to github repo:
https://github.com/ddydeveloper/Roslyn.ApiClient.Codegen

Did anyone have such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The best way to generate body of the method is inserting into `List<StatementSyntax>` like this:

```
private static BlockSyntax GetMethodBody(BaseApiMethodInfo methodInfo, string controllerName)
{
    var statements = new List<StatementSyntax>();

    ...

    statements.Add(ParseStatement($"var handle = Client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));"));
    statements.Add(ParseStatement($"var response = await taskCompletion.Task;"));
    statements.Add(ParseStatement($"return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<{TypesHelper.GetTypeName(methodInfo.ReturnedType)}>(response.Content);"));

    return Block(statements);
}
```

After this you just adding BlockSyntax to your method declaration, for example using `.WithBody(body)`

Answer (score 0):

Call [`Formatter.FormatAsync()`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs,80) to run Roslyn's formatter.

Comment: I tried to call `Formatter.FormatAsync`. Unfortunately it did't helps me. I also had problems with Mircosoft.CodeAnalysis nuget packages compatibility in .net core application because of using Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27.